# How to validate multiple form fields at once in Play?

Tags: forms, validation, playframework, playframework-2.3

So I have a form object:

```
  object RegisterForm {
   case class registerFormData(
      name: String,
      email: String,
      repeatemail: String,
      password: String,
      repeatpassword: String,
      timezone: Option[Int],
      dob: Int,
      accept: Boolean
  )
  val registerForm: Form[registerFormData] = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> nonEmptyText,
      "repeatemail" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
      "repeatpassword" -> nonEmptyText,
      "timezone" -> optional(number),
      "dob" -> number,
      "accept" -> checked("Please accept the terms and conditions.")
    )(registerFormData.apply)(registerFormData.unapply)
  )
}
```

Can I validate multiple fields at once like I can in Play in Java?

For example, can I validate to check that password and repeatpassword are equal, check to make sure the username is not taken, then send the form back showing both errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would be better:

```
case class User(
   name: String,
   email: String,
   password: String,
   timezone: Option[Int],
   dob: Int,
   accept: Boolean
)

val registerForm: Form[User] = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText,
      "email" -> tuple(
          "main" -> nonEmptyText,
          "confirm" -> nonEmptyText
      ).verifying(
           "Emails don't match", email => email._1 == email._2
      ).transform[String](
          email => email._1,      // Transform to a single field
          email => (email, email) // Reverse transform from a single field to multiple
      ),
      "password" -> tuple(
          "main" -> nonEmptyText,
          "confirm" -> nonEmptyText
      ).verifying(
           "Passwords don't match", password => password._1 == password._2
      ).transform[String](
          password => password._1,
          password => ("", "")
      ),
      "timezone" -> optional(number),
      "dob" -> number,
      "accept" -> checked("Please accept the terms and conditions.")
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
)
```

I'd personally also remove `accept` from the `Form` itself, and just prevent users from using the submit button before the "accept" checkbox has been checked. Using this method, you reduce the amount of garbage introduced into the case class, and the need for a separate one at all. Your form fields in HTML would look like this:

```
Email: <input type="text" name="email.main">
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email.confirm">
```

You can also use `verifying` to check within the `Form` if a user name or email address is already in use, but I would save that for *after* the `Form` has been successfully bound.

If you had a function like `User.findByEmail(string)` that returned `Option[User]`, you could add to the email field within the `Form`:

```
.verifying("Email address is already in use", email => User.findByEmail(email).isEmpty)
```

Comment: How to highlight both `password.main` and `password.confirm` fields in the template? Thx.

Comment: @Way That depends on how you want to highlight them. I'd suggest asking a new question with the code you're currently using, and possibly referencing this question.

Comment: New thread created. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259403/how-to-show-field-error-inline-in-the-form