# How to show field error inline in the form?

Tags: scala, validation, playframework

I defined a case class and a form object to handle form submission.

```
case class NewUser(
  userName: String,
  password: String,
  email: String  
)

val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "userName" -> nonEmptyText.verifying("The username already exists", User.userNameExists(_) == false),
    "password" -> tuple(
    "main" -> nonEmptyText,
    "confirm" -> nonEmptyText
  ).verifying(
    "Password does not match confirmed password", password => password._1 == password._2
  ).transform[String](
    password => password._1,
    password => ("", "")
  ),
  "email" -> email.verifying("This email belongs to an existing account. Please try another one", emailExists(_) == false))
  (NewUser.apply)(NewUser.unapply)
)
```

In the template, the code as blow:

```
@helper.inputText(newUserForm("userName"), 'class -> "form-control", 'required -> "true")
@helper.inputPassword(newUserForm("password.main"), 'class -> "form-control", 'required -> "true")
@helper.inputPassword(newUserForm("password.confirm"), 'class -> "form-control", 'required -> "true")
@helper.inputText(newUserForm("email"), 'class -> "form-control")
```

If the user types an existing userName, the error will be displayed inline. However, if the user types `confirm password` different from `password`, the error is not displayed anywhere.

How to display the error inline? Could anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: No. :(. Any suggestion?

Comment: Keep your verifying this way. In the controller, it will be a form with error (as expected), so in your fold, create an if condition (your password check) and if true, then use .withError("password", "passwords not matching" )